# JAVA Recursion and Iteration Methods

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

Hi I just have a quick question regarding my code, I need to know where the error is and why it's not displaying the recursive and iterative methods correctly (this returns a stackoverflow error). Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Progression {
    public static int geometricRecursive(int x){
        if(x  == 1)
            return 1;
        else {
            return x * geometricRecursive(x - 1);
        } 
    }

    public static int harmonicRecursive(int x){
        if(x == 1)
            return 1;
        else {
            return x * harmonicRecursive(1/(x - 1));
        }
    }

    public static int geometricIterative(int num){
        int result = 0;
        if(result == 1)
            return result;
        else
            for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
                result = (i * (i + 1));
            }
        return result;
    }

    public static int harmonicIterative(int num){
        int result = 0;
        if (result == 1)
            return result;
        else
            for (int i = 2; i < num; i ++){
                result = (i * (1/(i+1)));
            }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("This program will calculate the geometric and ");
        System.out.println("harmonic progression for the number you enter.");
        System.out.print("Enter an integer that is greater than or equal to 1: ");
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        int geomAnswer = geometricRecursive (input);
        double harmAnswer = harmonicRecursive (input);
        System.out.println("Using recursion:");
        System.out.println("The geometric progression of " + input + " is " + geomAnswer);
        System.out.println("The harmonic progression of " + input + " is " + harmAnswer);
        geomAnswer = geometricIterative (input);
        harmAnswer = harmonicIterative (input);
        System.out.println("Using iteration:");
        System.out.println("The geometric progression of " + input + " is " + geomAnswer);
        System.out.println("The harmonic progression of " + input + " is " + harmAnswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace?  What have you tried in terms of debugging?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I mean what do you get that you dont want/expect?

Comment: ARe you aware of the limitations of integer types regarding division?

Comment: Also, for functions with "harmonic", you should use `double`, not `int`

Comment: upto which point it runs?

Comment: Is it me or will harmonicRecursive never terminate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a StackOverflow, because you are not performing the divisions correctly. You are doing integer divisions, which yields a wrong result. This causes not reaching your base-condition in your recursion algorithm.

To fix it, use doubles and change the base condition:

```
public static double harmonicRecursive(double x)
{
   if(x <= 1.0)
   {
       return 1.0;
   }
   else
   {
       return x * harmonicRecursive(1.0 / (x - 1.0));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The offending line is `return x * harmonicRecursive(1/(x - 1));` in the `harmonicRecursive(int x)` method. The `1/(x - 1)` portion of the code will return `0` for all `x > 2`.  Your `if` statement only checks for `x == 1` which is an issue if you enter anything larger than 2 into that function.

Answer (score 1):

Change this method in this way:

```
public static int harmonicRecursive(int x){

   if(x <= 1) //Here

       return 1;

   else {

      return x * harmonicRecursive(1/(x - 1));

   }
}
```

Comment: Also change the input to be a `double`